# ¿Es posible usar argumentos en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Dado el array de varias imágenes locales, deseo crear un componente que tenga la lógica para anclar las imágenes que cada componente requiera, pero que tenga una base igual hablando de estilo. En resumen, un componente que tenga un estilo específico que sea reutilizable a la hora de llamarlo en un container y asimismo, tenga los argumentos para poner las imágenes que cada componente requiere. ¿Es posible?

Comment: Sí, es posible.

Comment: podes creara un modulo que contenga al componente que mencionas y lo exporte y luego compartir ese modulo con los módulos que lo requieran